# Make book title upright when using natbibapa {apacite}

Tags: natbib, apa-style

To comply with the formatting style of my university, I would need to change only the book title style from italicized to upright in the bibliography. Is there an easy way to do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@book{sorensen2010introducing,
Author = {S{\o}rensen, Peter Birch and Whitta-Jacobsen, Hans J{\o}rgen},
Date-Modified = {2015-03-13 19:15:01 +0000},
Keywords = {master thesis},
Publisher = {McGraw-Hill higher education},
Title = {Introducing advanced macroeconomics: growth and business cycles},
Year = {2010}
}
```

**What it looks like:**

[image: apacite output]

**What it should look like:**

Sørensen, P. B. and Whitta-Jacobsen, H. J. (2010). Introducing advanced macroeconomics:                             growth and business cycles. McGraw-Hill higher education.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: you seem to be mixing `biblatex` (`\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography`) commands with a regular `bibtex` package.  And the `apacite` package is designed to be used with the `apacite` bibliography style.  Either use `apacite` or use `biblatex-apa`; you can't use both.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Sorry, I'm quite new to stackexchange and latex. I think the minimum working example should compile now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use all features of `apacite`, change `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`.  One of the important features is the customization.  In particular, the formatting of book titles in `apacite` is determined by the command `\APACrefbtitle` defined as:

```
 \newcommand{\APACrefbtitle}[2]{\Bem{#2}}
```

Here `\Bem` is normally `\emph`.

Now let us just redefine the book title formatting command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\renewcommand{\APACrefbtitle}[2]{#2}
\begin{document}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds. :) I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Sometimes you beat me :)